# No module named 'qiskit'

Tags: python, qiskit

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
from qiskit import execute
```

---

When trying the above code, I am receiving the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 import numpy as np
>   ----> 2 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
>         3 from qiskit import execute
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install it via

```
pip install qiskit
```

Refer to this for more information https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/blob/master/docs/install.rst

Comment: `$pip install qiskit`
Collecting qiskit
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qiskit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for qiskit

Comment: ```$ pip3 install qiskit
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra<0.8,>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from qiskit) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-aer<0.2,>=0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packag....```

Comment: also it could be installed but not activated so please make sure you run "conda activate ur_env_name" you may created with conda or whatever your vm.

Answer (score 4):

You need Python 3:

```
pip3 install qiskit
```

Refer to this for more information:
 https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/1751

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the command;

`pip install qiskit`  or

`pip3 install qiskit`  (For Python 3.x+)

depending on the version of Python you're using.